# Parse specific tag in XML file

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, xpath, visual-studio-2013

I am using XPath to try and get filepaths from my XML file, but the message box with the filepath information never pops up...

### XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<csvcData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/csvcData.xsd">
  <fileLocations>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <filePath>\Check Quotes\report.xlsx</filePath>
  </fileLocations>
  <fileLocations>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <filePath>\Check Quotes\smartListReport.xlsx</filePath>
  </fileLocations>
</csvcData>
```

### VB.NET Code

```
Using File As New FileStream(_dataPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim Doc As New XPathDocument(File)
    Dim Nav = Doc.CreateNavigator

    Dim fPath = Nav.Select("//csvcData/fileLocations/filePath")
    While fPath.MoveNext
        Dim msg = MsgBox("Filepath : " + fPath.Current.Value)
    End While
End Using
```

The message box never shows up... I have all of the required imports, my code compiles and executes properly otherwise.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the document has a default namespace defined at the root element.  That means that, even though the namespace isn't explicitly declared for any of the nodes, they are all actually in that namespace.  XPath in .NET has no concept of default namespaces.  As such, if you want to select any of those nodes with XPath, you are going to have to explicitly declare the namespace for each one, like this:

```
Dim manager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(Nav.NameTable)
manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://tempuri.org/csvcData.xsd")
Dim fPath = Nav.Select("//d:csvcData/d:fileLocations/d:filePath", manager)
```

Comment: any significance behind choosing `"d"` as the prefix?

Comment: No, it can be anything you want.  I just chose "d" to stand for "Data" (as in "csvcData").

Comment: Out of curiosity if I didn't want to add a namespace how would I do this? `Dim fPath = Nav.Select("//http://tempuri.org/csvcData.xsd:csvcData/http://tempuri.org/csvcData.xsd:fileLocations/http://tempuri.org/csvcData.xsd:filePath")`

Comment: That is invalid.  You can't use the actual namespace URI in-line in XML nor in XPath.  You have to declare the namespace with a prefix and then use that prefix everywhere to specify which namespace you are using.  The prefix is irrelevant.  You can use a different prefix to refer to the same namespace in each document, or even in different elements of the same document.  The URI is the unique part that always has to be the same because that's the actual ID that uniquely identifies that namespace.  But you can give it any prefix you want.

Comment: ok, awesome. works like a charm. Is there anyway to get the namespace of the file if I don't know it?

Comment: Absolutely.  You can select the `/csvcData` element and then read it's `Current.NamespaceURI` property to get the namespace URI for it.